# cannot change CheckButton variable value

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

I have a little problem with the checkbtn value.

Here is my code:

```
def select_data():
        select_window = Tk()

        var_autotrader = IntVar()
        check_sites_autotrader = Checkbutton(select_window, text = 'autotrader', variable = var_autotrader)
        var_bestcarfinder = IntVar()
        var_cardady = IntVar()
        var_cars = IntVar()
        var_car_gurus = IntVar()
        var_iseecars = IntVar()
        var_truecar = IntVar()

        check_sites_bestcarfinder = Checkbutton(select_window, text = 'bestcarfinder', variable = var_bestcarfinder)
        check_sites_cardaddy = Checkbutton(select_window, text = 'cardady', variable = var_cardady)
        check_sites_cars = Checkbutton(select_window, text = 'cars.com', variable = var_cars)
        check_sites_car_gurus = Checkbutton(select_window, text = 'car gurus', variable = var_car_gurus)
        check_sites_iseecars = Checkbutton(select_window, text = 'iseecars', variable = var_iseecars)
        check_sites_truecar = Checkbutton(select_window, text = 'truecar', variable = var_truecar)

        check_sites_autotrader.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        check_sites_bestcarfinder.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
        check_sites_cardaddy.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        check_sites_cars.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        check_sites_car_gurus.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
        check_sites_iseecars.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)
        check_sites_truecar.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)
         def upload_selected_data():
            print(var_autotrader.get())// This one does not give me 1 when check is on
            

        btn = Button(select_window, text = 'go!',  command = upload_selected_data)
        btn.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W+E)
```

The trouble is that my variable is not changing when I check the box

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Checkbuttons not changing the variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012487/tkinter-checkbuttons-not-changing-the-variable-value)

Comment: No, becasue that window this is a main window. Thank you!

Comment: The code you posted works as expected for me on python 3.6.8 Win10. I think more code or information is needed to see where your problem is since it doesn't seem to be in this isolated piece of code.

Comment: Does this code _really_ reproduce the problem? I don't see where you're calling `mainloop`, so it would be impossible for the user to even see the window much less interact with it. There also appears to be an indentation error with `def upload_selected_data`

Comment: If `select_window` is passed to all `IntVar()` like `IntVar(select_window)`, do you get what you want? If yes, then it is definitely `select_window` is not the root window.

Comment: If you are using `Tk()` more than once in your entire app, that is your problem. You need to change all `Tk()` (except the very first one) to `Toplevel()`

Comment: Michael Guidry, thank you very much! It Worked! Make it as a post, to mark as answer, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you created your "main window" with `Tk()`. In this case you should create another window with the `Toplevel()` (Not with `Tk()`).

It means in your case you should change the `select_window = Tk()` line to `select_window = Toplevel()`